# Not work clipboard between Windows and Linux Mint 18.3 (Virtual box) machine

Tags: virtualbox

My main machine - **Windows 10** .
On VirtualBox I install by ISO file the **Linux Mint 18.3**.
On VirtualBox machine I set this settings for share clipboards:

[image]

But when I copy text to clipboard on Windows machine it not paste on Linux machine. And visa versa.
Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you installed the guest addtions? They are needed to have features like this.
(QUICK GUID -> Within the guest terminal window, click on the devices from the menu, then "Insert Guest Addtions CD Image", then try to install them by the script found in the optical drive)

[Virtual Box Manual - Chapter 4](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html)